# How to use the output of a shell plugin in UCD in the next consecutive steps

Tags: shell, urbancode, ucd

For Eg:

testingABoolean=test

if [ $testingABoolean = "test" ]; then
isBoolean=true
else
isBoolean=false
fi

---

Here I want to use "isBoolean" in the next steps of UCD